# Amazon Linux httpd redirecting to www not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am actually trying to do 2 **things**:

```
 1. convert site port from 80 to 3000 
 2. redirect site from example.com to www.example.com
```

My machine is amazon linux, so using http

so in **httpd.conf** file, below is what I've added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On


    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^www\." [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^$"
    RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"      "http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1" [L,R,NE]


     # setup the proxy
     <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
     </Proxy>
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

In above, port changing is working, but **redirecting** to **www** **not working**, could you please suggest me what changes I need to make, to make it to work in above.

Comment: why do you need the second `RewriteCond` ? Isn't the first one enough for the redirect ? Have you already tried to comment that line ?

Comment: @Leonardo I've tried commenting RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^$" , but still redirect not working.. can you please test above code and tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Your VirtualHost is defined with `ServerName example.com`.  But not www.example.com.  So what happens then?  Apache will use the first VirtualHost if finds.  It would be best to add `ServerAlias www.example.com` to ensure the proper VirtualHost is used.  R=301 would be good as well, this way the redirect stays permanent in the browser for it's entire life.